# Is there some little system tray program for windows that keeps checking an svn repository to see if there's been new updates?

Tags: svn

It would be nice to have something check if there's been commits to the repository lately, and  let me know with a nice system tray popup.

Maybe the thing could check every 10 minutes or so.

Is there such a thing out there I can download, or do I have to make one?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the Subversion repository you could set up a post-commit hook to notify you of a new revision.

Comment: I suppose that would be more efficient wouldn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another one called commit monitor but i haven't tried it yet

http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html

Comment: sometimes it's just knowing the correct terms to search on :)

Comment: i'm at the end of a long day, and i just spent half an hour wondering why one guys build had a bug and mine didnt... i forgot to update :(

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnmonitor/

Comment: looks like something worth trying.

Comment: Downloaded their latest source, there was one compilation error and its svn client is not compatible with my current working copy version.

Answer (score 1):

[Vercue](http://www.vercue.com/), former SVNNonitor from SharpRegion.

Professional version *can be better*, than Free (see comparision table at the bottom of linked page), but it costs